# How can automatically restart a (vlc) video stream?

Tags: video, vlc, streaming

At work we have an "camera pc" which monitors an ipcam.
I'm using rtsp and VLC to display te stream on a monitor.
However, the stream is eating up approximately 50GB a day so I edited the crontab to disable the eth0 interface between 17.00 and 8:30.
The problem is that VLC won't reconnect when the interface is back up in the morning and of course I want it to happen automatically..

I tried setting the camera settings lower, but VLC will only display a black screen.

So if anybody has any suggestions, I'm all ears..

Tl;dr : How can I set VLC to automatically reconnect a video stream?

Answer (score 3):

Try starting vlc with --loop parameter.
If VLC recognizes the stream has stopped, it should restart when it resumes.